# How can you re-order the options of a Facebook Question?

Tags: facebook, facebook-questions

Not sure if this feature is new, or just exploding in use, but there is an option to create polls (Questions) for your friendbase on facebook.  I created a question, but I want to re-arrange the options without re-creating the list.  Is there any way to do this?

Secondary question - what's the best way to submit feature requests or feedback to facebook, if there really is no such feature?

Comment: Of note - as questions are answered, they are sorted by popularity.  So I think there may be no way to re-order the list.  However, a way to re-order it on the initial creation would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method to do this currently.  Facebook has it's own 
sorting mechanism that occurs once answers are accepted.

The only method to achieve what I wanted is to pre-plan the list,
then initially enter it in the desired order.